# breaking down ouput per timestamp by group on mysql

Tags: mysql

New to mysql,

Under one table(table called tableX), let’s say structure is like below

```
server       date           numberofUser
 server1   timestamp        3
 server2   timestamp        2
 server3   timestamp        7
 server1   timestamp        2
 server2   timestamp        8
 server3   timestamp        4
```

I want to collect for last 100 occurrence(so by the timestamp) but for each timestamp(which means for timestampX(which all server1,2,3 are measured), I want to total numberofUser for server1 and server 2.

So desire output is

```
timestamp1     5     (which comes from server1(2)  and server2(3) added
timestamp2     24    (which comes from server1(12) and server2(12) added
timestamp3     7     (which comes from server1(3) and server2(4) added
```

Can someone please point me to right direction? thank you

I already got total for last x occurrence of all servers(server 1 and 2) as below which works fine but now I need to break down by each timestamp

```
select sum(numberofUser) from (
    (select  server,   date, numberofUser from tableX 
    where server = 'server1'
    order by date limit 10)
    union
   ( select  server,   date, numberofUser from tableX 
    where server = 'server2'
    order by date limit 10 )) as t
```

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::UPDATE::::::::::::::::::

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bc7f/1

I have my scheme above

output I want to see is below for given scheme

```
date1                   total
1970-01-01 00:00:03       85
1970-01-01 00:00:04       125
```

Comment: also, can someone recommend me a book or tutorial for topic like this?

Comment: I could help with this, so could anyone, if you created a sqlfiddle, loaded it with real data, and showed a columnar table with formatting showing expected results. As is, this is pretty bad.

Comment: I guess my example is pretty bad? Sorry, but I really don't understand simple problem like this is so difficult to figure out for newbie and was hoping to get some material to comb through. I am looking at some books now and struggle a bit on my own to see if I can figure it out. thank you guys!

Comment: well load up a fiddle at least and we can help, like this guy did in his [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37713790) .... and show what with that fiddle (you only do the left side) what you want your output to look like

Comment: Ok, I updated the original at the bottom w/ fiddle and desired outcome

Comment: Perfect, thx. I am sure someone can help. If not, I will.

Comment: Great! also, if you can recommend any resource, I would love to study further upon on this subject. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to hit your desired output you would have to do `limit 2` not the 100 you mention in your question. The second query uses a derived table on the inside that enforces the last ones first (the limit 2), with the outer query flipping the results to ordered as you showed.

```
select date1,sum(numOfUsers) as total 
from test1 
where server in ('server1','server2') 
group by date1 
order by date1 desc 
limit 2; 
+---------------------+-------+
| date1               | total |
+---------------------+-------+
| 1970-01-01 00:00:04 |   125 |
| 1970-01-01 00:00:03 |    85 |
+---------------------+-------+
```

### Your final query is

```
select date1,total 
from 
(   select date1,sum(numOfUsers) as total 
    from test1 
    where server in ('server1','server2') 
    group by date1 
    order by date1 desc 
    limit 2 
) xDerived 
order by date1; 
+---------------------+-------+
| date1               | total |
+---------------------+-------+
| 1970-01-01 00:00:03 |    85 |
| 1970-01-01 00:00:04 |   125 |
+---------------------+-------+
```

`xDerived` is merely an alias name. Every derived table requires an alias name even if not used explicitly thereafter. Regardless of how silly it looks.

Comment: I am so sorry, where is xDerived coming from? When I google, I get nothing.

Comment: I accepted the answer but I don't understand the xDerived

Comment: I tweaked it slightly. Similar to the derived tables `xParams1` and `xParams2` in the final chunk answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37791885). Those were two little mini tables used to pump prime some variables used.