# Excluding some combinations from left join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I'm analyzing game data. My data includes game id (GID), player id (PID), and Time slice (T),.... Table A and B are two tables that created by my queries as follow:

```
Table A
GID, PID, T, command_freq, command_id
1,   1,   0, 17, 10
1,   1,   0, 4, 5
1,   1,   1, 26, 10
1,   1,   1, 6, 5
1,   1,   2, 5, 5
1,   1,   2, 3, 10
1,   1,   5, 7, 10

Table B
GID, PID, T, order_freq, order_id
 1,  1,   0, 7, 40
 1,  1,   2, 3, 40
 1,  1,   2, 11, 42
 1,  1,   5, 1, 40
```

I need to find in which commands and orders are done in each time slice (also their counts). The result should be as follows:

```
GID, PID, T, command_count, command_id, order_count, order_id
1,   1,   0,  17,           10,            Null, Null
1,   1,   0,  4,            5 ,            Null, Null
1,   1,   0,  Null,         Null,          7, 40
1,   1,   1,  26,           10,            Null, Null
1,   1,   1,  6,            5,             Null, Null
1,   1,   2,  5,            5,             Null, Null
1,   1,   2,  3,            10,            Null, Null
1,   1,   2,  Null,         Null,          3, 40
1,   1,   2,  Null,         Null,          11, 42
1,   1,   5,  7,            10,            Null, Null
1,   1,   5,  Null,         Null,          1, 40
```

In general in T=t we could have 0 to n commands or orders. I need the union of all commands and orders for T=t.

Comment: So if t = 0 then don't join else join on gid,pid and t?

Comment: conditional joins often use left joins or union strategies

Comment: Are the 1,1,6 combos missing on purpose or is this a mistake in the result set displayed?

Comment: @P.Salmon : 1.1.6 is missed in result set.

Comment: @Drew I'm looking for the condition.

Comment: The condition is the use of `!=` and `=` as seen in the first answer

Comment: After your edit, I would suggest you just clean the whole question up, remove blocks that don't matter, and explain *why* or *how* (at a high level) you want the expected results. That way people have less of a puzzle to figure out. I say this because people will just leave for another question, generally.

Comment: @Drew Ok. I will try to explain in high level.

Comment: I think your expected results are messed up. The ones up top are not sharing the rows with 1,1,0 and as such exhibit a union (not a left join). On the other hand, the ones on the bottom exhibit the sharing of a row data for output and therefore a left join and not a union.

Comment: So, you never took the pain to describe why or how you want data to appear. Instead you just plopped it, leaving us to figure out what you were thinking. That may be fine for stuff obvious to everyone. I don't know. Maybe I am just slow today and need better glasses.

Comment: @Drew Sorry, the problem wasn't clear for myself. Now I think the question is more clear. I need the union of two (later multiple) tables that have same values for GID, PID, and T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Schema

```
drop table if exists ta;
create table ta (GID int,PID int,T int,command_freq int, command_id int);
insert into ta values
(1,   1,   0, 17, 10),
(1,   1,   0, 4, 5),
(1,   1,   1, 26, 10),
(1,   1,   1, 6, 5),
(1,   1,   2, 5, 5),
(1,   1,   2, 3, 10),
(1,   1,   5, 7, 10);

drop table if exists tb;
create table tb (gid int,pid int,t int,order_freq int,order_id int);
insert into tb values
( 1,  1,   0, 7, 40),
( 1,  1,   2, 3, 40),
( 1,  1,   2, 11, 42),
( 1,  1,   5, 1, 40);
```

Note that with the use of unions, the first query in a union drives what the column names are targeted as for the final output:

```
GID, PID, T, command_count, command_id, order_count, order_id
```

So the 2nd and thereafter queries in a union can be sloppy about it if they want, at least insofar as their alleged column names.

The first query below, though it generates the **same** output at least shown to you **here** via the command line utility output, delivers slightly different results than the second query if I run it thru MySQL Workbench.

```
select GID,PID,T,command_count,command_id,order_count,order_id 
from 
(   select GID, PID, T, command_freq as command_count, command_id, null as order_count, null as order_id, 1 as theOrder from ta 
    union  
    select GID, PID, T, null as command_count, null, order_freq as order_count, order_id, 2 as theOrder from tb 
) xDerived 
order by GID,PID,T,theOrder; 
+------+------+------+---------------+------------+-------------+----------+
| GID  | PID  | T    | command_count | command_id | order_count | order_id |
+------+------+------+---------------+------------+-------------+----------+
|    1 |    1 |    0 |            17 |         10 |        NULL |     NULL |
|    1 |    1 |    0 |             4 |          5 |        NULL |     NULL |
|    1 |    1 |    0 |          NULL |       NULL |           7 |       40 |
|    1 |    1 |    1 |            26 |         10 |        NULL |     NULL |
|    1 |    1 |    1 |             6 |          5 |        NULL |     NULL |
|    1 |    1 |    2 |             5 |          5 |        NULL |     NULL |
|    1 |    1 |    2 |             3 |         10 |        NULL |     NULL |
|    1 |    1 |    2 |          NULL |       NULL |          11 |       42 |
|    1 |    1 |    2 |          NULL |       NULL |           3 |       40 |
|    1 |    1 |    5 |             7 |         10 |        NULL |     NULL |
|    1 |    1 |    5 |          NULL |       NULL |           1 |       40 |
+------+------+------+---------------+------------+-------------+----------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The second version below takes the minor additional effort to use a rownum to hit your result ordering if that was even important inside of the `GID,PID,T` blocks. The second result set shows the same ordering for me at least via the mysql command line tool and MySQL Workbench:

```
select GID,PID,T,command_count,command_id,order_count,order_id 
from 
(   select GID, PID, T, command_freq as command_count, command_id, null as order_count, null as order_id, 1 as theOrder,@rn1:=@rn1+1 as rownum 
    from ta 
    cross join (select @rn1:=0) xParams1 
    union  
    select GID, PID, T, null as command_count, null, order_freq as order_count, order_id, 2 as theOrder,@rn2:=@rn2+1 as rownum   from tb 
    cross join (select @rn2:=0) xParams2 
) xDerived 
order by GID,PID,T,theOrder,rownum; 
+------+------+------+---------------+------------+-------------+----------+
| GID  | PID  | T    | command_count | command_id | order_count | order_id |
+------+------+------+---------------+------------+-------------+----------+
|    1 |    1 |    0 |            17 |         10 |        NULL |     NULL |
|    1 |    1 |    0 |             4 |          5 |        NULL |     NULL |
|    1 |    1 |    0 |          NULL |       NULL |           7 |       40 |
|    1 |    1 |    1 |            26 |         10 |        NULL |     NULL |
|    1 |    1 |    1 |             6 |          5 |        NULL |     NULL |
|    1 |    1 |    2 |             5 |          5 |        NULL |     NULL |
|    1 |    1 |    2 |             3 |         10 |        NULL |     NULL |
|    1 |    1 |    2 |          NULL |       NULL |           3 |       40 |
|    1 |    1 |    2 |          NULL |       NULL |          11 |       42 |
|    1 |    1 |    5 |             7 |         10 |        NULL |     NULL |
|    1 |    1 |    5 |          NULL |       NULL |           1 |       40 |
+------+------+------+---------------+------------+-------------+----------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In either case, the `theOrder` column was used to force the output of `NULL` to be at the bottom of each `GID,PID,T` block.

I present them as a way for you to visualize the use of variables and ordering to hit your desired output ordering as you make changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @A table (gid int,pid int,t int,f1 int, f2 int)
insert into @a values
(1,   1,   0, 17, 10),
(1,   1,   0, 4, 5),
(1,   1,   1, 26, 10),
(1,   1,   1, 6, 5),
(1,   1,   2, 5, 5),
(1,   1,   2, 3, 10),
(1,   1,   5, 7, 10),
(1,   1,   6, 3, 7),
(1,   1,   6, 8, 5)

declare @b table (gid int,pid int,t int,f3 int,f4 int)
insert into @b
values
( 1,  1,   0, 7, 40),
( 1,  1,   2, 3, 40),
( 1,  1,   5, 1, 40)


select  a.gid,a.pid,a.t,a.f1,a.f2,b.f3,b.f4 
from    @a a
join    @b b on b.gid = a.gid and b.pid = a.pid and b.t = a.t
where   a.t <> 0
union
select  a.gid,a.pid,a.t,a.f1,a.f2,null,null
from    @a a
where   a.t = 0
union
select  b.gid,b.pid,b.t,null,null,b.f3,b.f4
from    @b b
where   b.t = 0
```